# unknown variable 'log_slow_verbosity=query_plan'

Tags: mysql, mariadb, my.cnf

What is the use of `log_slow_verbosity = query_plan` parameter in `my.cnf` ?

I got an error when installing MySQL in my machine because of this parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[log_slow_verbosity](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/server-system-variables/#log_slow_verbosity) is for MariaDB, not MySQL

Perhaps your OS has MariaDB repos installed instead of MySQL. If you downloaded MySQL and installed it, mysqld encountered an already existing `my.cnf` that was for MariaDB.

Comment: I have been removed my.cnf file before installing mysql but still i got an error then after i removed log_slow_verbosity = query_plan from my.cnf and installed MySQL.Now MySQL running perfectly.

Comment: This variable was added to the my,cnf file during a recent update of software on Ubuntu 18.04. Removing the line from my.cnf fixed this.